# Is this application of Abstract data types in C equivalent to functional programming?

Tags: c, design-patterns, functional-programming

With the following code

```cpp
typedef struct Customer* CustomerPtr;

typedef struct Order* OrderPtr;

CustomerPtr createCustomer(const char* name, const Address* address);

void destroyCustomer(CustomerPtr customer); 

void placeOrder(const CustomerPtr customer, const OrderPtr order);
```

the `placeOrder` function is only dependent on the input parameters, and if `Customer` and `Order` do not have side-effects, then it appears to be a pure function.

I have the following 2 questions based on the observation:

1. Is this indeed the same as functional programming?
2. 1. If yes, then are there any patterns from functional programming that might be available for implementation in this straightforward fashion?
      I would like to avoid function composition using function pointers as it makes the code feel quite unreadable.
   2. If no, what is the differentiating factor here?

Code referred from Adam Tornhill's articles on [Patterns in C](https://www.adamtornhill.com/Patterns%20in%20C%201.pdf)

Comment: A hallmark of functional programming is the use of higher-order functions. C does not support first-class higher-order functions (at least not without a lot of legwork).

Comment: @Dai it can still have a subset of the paradigm, I am by no means trying to qualify C as a functional language, but only estimating the applicability of functional reasoning to it.